# How to apply stimulus to an array through a testbench

Tags: verilog

I want to apply some values to input "in " through the testbench . Tb part is attached below , I know it is wrong, how can one do this in verilog ?

```
reg clk;
reg reset;
reg [size-1:0] in[elements_num-1:0];
wire   [size-1:0] variance;
wire  [size-1:0] mob;
wire  [size-1:0] com;


mobility  dut (
            .clk(clk),
            .in(in[elements_num-1:0]),
            .reset(reset),
            .variance(variance),
            .mob(mob),
            .com(com)
    );
```

Comment: What values do you want to apply and when?

Comment: what do you think is wrong with the tb part? Your code cold be ok or not, depending on the rest of the program. However, it does not apply any values to anything.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to initialize the memory from a file. You can use 'readmemh' (hex) or 'readmemb' (binary) functions for this.

```
initial
begin
    $readmemb("your_memory_contents.txt", in);
end
```

And you can use a file like following for 'your_memory_contents.txt':

```
00000001
00010000
00010010
...
```